# Element is not found even assertExist is true in casperjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, casperjs

In my application, I am facing an issue in `casperjs`.

Steps I am doing as follows.

1) first I am doing assertion, whether element exists or not.

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.test.assertExists(
            { type: 'xpath', path: '//header[@id="masthead"]/section[3]/div/div/nav/ul[1]/li[2]/a[1]' },
            'the element exists'
    );
});
```

Output : Pass

2) click on that element

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.click(x('//header[@id="masthead"]/section[3]/div/div/nav/ul[1]/li[2]/a[1]'));
    this.echo('clicking product and services enter code here page');
});
```

Output : clicking product and services page

3) capturing the image.

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.echo("Capturing image website");
    this.capture('images/po/productServices.png', {
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0
    });   
});
```

Output : image is not coming with what exactly i want when click that element.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Narasaiah p

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify `width` and `height` here:

```
width: viewport.viewport.width,
height: viewport.viewport.height
```

instead of:

```
width: 0,
height: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a wait instruction -waitForSelector, waitForUrl, waitForText...- in 3) after your click :

exemple :

```
casper.waitForSelector('the selector to wait before taking the capture', function() {
    this.capture('images/po/productServices.png');
});
```